# Laravel 5.2 {{ env('APP_ENV') }} does not work in production

Tags: apache2, laravel-5, laravel-blade

The following code works on my development environment (Ubuntu 14.04 desktop)

```
@if(env('APP_ENV') === 'production')
    // ... something
```

But for some reason, the blade views on production (ubuntu 14.04 server) aren't getting the env variables.

If I run `php artisan env` the response is just fine: **Current application environment: production**

The database connection works fine. And the env() helper called from the controllers, also works.

What I tried so far:

`php artisan clear:cache`
`php artisan config:cache`
`php artisan clear:cache`
`php artisan view:clear`

I also restarted apache multiple times, no results.

Any advice?
Thanks!

Comment: what do you get if you `{{ dd(env('APP_ENV')) }}` in your template?

Comment: @Rob null in production, "local" in local env.

Comment: did you forget to create your `.env` file? pretty sure laravel uses production by default but i don't know what you've changed.

Comment: Nope, .env file exists and works fine with laravel except for views. The database connection works fine, and I CAN access env variables from controllers. The problem is with the views.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

So, I made it work.

`php artisan config:clear` did the trick.

1. `php artisan config:clear`
2. `php artisan cache:clear`
3. `service apache2 restart` (just in case)

**What I guess the problem was:**

The first time I run `php artisan config:cache` my .env file had APP_ENV=local. So I had to clear that config cache in order to get the new env vars values.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with:

```
rm bootstrap/cache/config.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `env()` use `\Config::get()` or `config()`.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration#configuration-caching

[What is difference between use env('APP_ENV'), config('app.env') or App::environment() to get app environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40026893/what-is-difference-between-use-envapp-env-configapp-env-or-appenviron)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.