# What is difference between use env('APP_ENV'), config('app.env') or App::environment() to get app environment?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, environment-variables, phpdotenv

What is difference between use `env('APP_ENV')`, `config('app.env')` or `App::environment()` to get app environment?

I know that the `env('APP_ENV')` will to `$_ENV`, `config('app.env')` reads the configuration and `App::environment()` is an abstraction of all. And in my opinion the advantage is even this. **Abstraction**.

I do not know if there are other differences, such as the level of performance or security

Comment: There are no _real_ differences (as the value comes from the same place: your *.env* file) but as a rule of thumb, you should rely on `config()` rather than `env()` directly if you wish to cache your configuration values.

Answer (score 100):

**In Short & up-to-date 2022:**

- use `env()` only in config files
- use `App::environment()` for checking the environment (APP_ENV in .env).
- use `config('app.var')` for all other env variables, ex: `config('app.debug')`
- create own config files for your own ENV variables. Example:
  In your .env:

  `MY_VALUE=foo`

example `config/myconfig.php`

```
return [
    'myvalue' => env('MY_VALUE', 'bar'), // 'bar' is default if MY_VALUE is missing in .env
];
```

Access in your code:

```
config('myconfig.myvalue') // will result in 'foo'
```

---

**Explanation & History:**

I just felt over it. When you cache your config file, `env()` will (sometimes?) not work right. So what I found out:

1. Laravel recommends only to use `env()` within the config files. Use the `config()` helper in your code instead of `env()`. For example you can call `config('app.env')` in your code.
2. When you use `php artisan config:cache` all the configuration strings are cached by the framework and any changes you make to your `.env` file will not be active until you run the `php artisan config:cache` command again.

From [this article](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/env-not-reading-variables-sometimes) on Laracast:

UPDATE:
`env()` calls work as long as you don't use `php artisan config:cache`. So it's very dangerous because it will often work while development **but will fail on production**. See [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0)

> **Caching And Env**
>
> If you are using the config:cache command during deployment, you must
> make sure that you are only calling the env function from within your
> configuration files, and not from anywhere else in your application.
>
> If you are calling env from within your application, it is strongly
> recommended you add proper configuration values to your configuration
> files and call env from that location instead, allowing you to convert
> your env calls to config calls.

UPDATE Laravel 5.6:
Laravel now recommends in its [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/configuration#determining-the-current-environment) to use

```
$environment = App::environment();

// or check on an array of environments:
if (App::environment(['local', 'staging'])) {
    // The environment is either local OR staging...
}
```

and [describes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/configuration#retrieving-environment-configuration) that `env()` is just to retrieve values from `.env` in config files, like `config('app.env')` or `config('app.debug')`.

Comment: Thanks for this! It's also referenced in the official docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration#configuration-caching

Comment: It is config('app.env') not config('APP_ENV')

Comment: did they change the docs? I did not find that they state anywhere that `App::environment()` is using `config('app.env')`.

Comment: The .env is where you set all your environment variables, so in the end App::environment() will get it from APP_ENV in the .env file. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#environment-configuration

Comment: "and describes that env() is just to retrieve values from .env in config files, like config('app.env') or config('app.debug')." - In 2021, Laravel 8.x, `config` should still be used in controllers, etc. no?

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler - Yes, in Controllers, etc. you should still use the config() helper.

Comment: A [use case or more about it](https://laraveldaily.com/how-to-add-new-env-variable-so-teammates-would-notice/).

Comment: @ndberg What's the reasoning for using `App::environment()` for env but `config()` for any other variables? I've heard some say that it's worse for performance to return the whole service container instance, but what are the upsides of doing it for the env variable? More secure?

Comment: @SeaBass Good question. My two points would be: If there is a official way to do something, do it like this - you'll get less problems. Secondly, I like the App::environment(['local', 'special']) helper to check if it's running in one of these environments. I don't thinkt that the performance impact is that big (in normal use cases)

Answer (score 14):

You have two equally good options

```
if (\App::environment('production')) {...}
```

or

```
if (app()->environment('production')) {...}
```

app()->environment() is actually used by [Bugsnag](https://www.bugsnag.com/), look in documentation [here](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/php/laravel/configuration-options/) it says

> By default, we’ll automatically detect the app environment by calling the environment() function on Laravel’s application instance.

Now, differences:

1) `env(...)` function returns null after caching config. It happens on production a lot.

2) you can change `config` parameters inside unit tests, it gives you flexibility while testing.

Answer (score 5):

One thing to consider is perhaps the convenience factor of passing string to `app()->environment()` in order validate your current environment.

```
// or App:: whichever you prefer.
if (app()->environment('local', 'staging')) {
    logger("We are not live yet!");
    Seeder::seedThemAll();
} else {
    logger("We are LIVE!");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**2023 Updated Answer**

`env()` helper works when there is no `config.php` inside `bootstrap/cache` directory

`config()` helper works both in case if the file `config.php` is present or not. If the file is not present then if will parse the variables at runtime, but if it does find one; it uses the cached version instead.

In production environment the `artisan` commands we run to add/remove the config file.php becomes of paramount importance in context of how `env()` and `config()` behave.

Consider the following example to understand the concept:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
  // to experiment: set APP_ENV=production in your .env file
  echo 'Via env(): ' . env('APP_ENV') . '<br/>'; // production
  echo 'Via config(): ' . config('app.env'); // production

  /*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | run: php artisan config:cache
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | The config:cache command will generate a configuration cache file (config.php) in the bootstrap/cache directory.
  | At this point, the env() helper will no longer work as all ENV variables will be flushed in favor of the cached config.php file.
  |
  */

  echo '<hr/>';

  echo 'Via env(): ' . env('APP_ENV') . '<br/>'; // null
  echo 'Via config(): ' . config('app.env'); // production

  /*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | run: php artisan config:clear
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | The config:clear command will remove (config.php) configuration cache file from the bootstrap/cache directory.
  | At this point, the env() helper will work again as framework doesn't find a cached configuration file.
  |
  */
  echo '<hr/>';

  echo 'Via env(): ' . env('APP_ENV') . '<br/>'; // production
  echo 'Via config(): ' . config('app.env'); // production
});
```

> So general rule of thumb is to always use `config()` helper inside your code files; in this way your code does not explode if cached configuration file is available or not.

Now getting the `environment` is so important and common; Laravel gives us a handful ways we can accomplish the same:

```
// APP_ENV=production inside .env file

App::environment(); // production
app()->environment(); // production


App::environment('production'); // returns boolean: true
app()->environment('production'); // return boolean: true
```

Keep in mind you are using `App` facade or `app()` helper they all will be using `config` helper under the hood.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the `config:cache` command during deployment, you must make sure that you are only calling the `env` function from within your configuration files, and not from anywhere else in your application.

If you are calling env from within your application, it is strongly recommended you add proper configuration values to your configuration files and call env from that location instead, allowing you to convert your `env` calls to config calls.

Add an env configuration option to your `app.php` configuration file that looks like the following:

```
'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),
```

More: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0

Answer (score 1):

In [12factor methodology](https://12factor.net/config) application contains two types of configuration values:

- internal which not vary between deploys and are stored in laravel `./config/` folder. In this type we usually store some technical optimal/good values used in application which should not be changed by users over time e.g. optimal image compression level, connection timeout, session expiration time etc.
- external which vary between deploys and are stored in `.env` file (but should not be stored in git repo, however `.env.example` with example values with detail info can be stored in repo). In this type we store usually some important/protected values which depends on local environment e.g. passwords, debug mode, db address etc.

Laravel proposes handy approach for this

- in regular code we use only `config(...)` helper (so on this level programmer do not need to know which configuration value is internal and which is external)
- in configuration code external config values should be set using `env(...)` helper e.g. in config/app.php `'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false)`