# Laravel - env() always returns null

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, phpdotenv

I try to find out why my `env()` helper always returns `null`. This causes trouble especially in `app.php` file, where are `env()` helpers widely used by default. Perhaps any mysterious server setting?

**My env file**:

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:mymagickey=
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_LOG_LEVEL=info
APP_URL=http://www.example.com

etc...
```

**EDIT - I tried following**:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

and ofcourse, i am using `env` helper like this: `env('APP_ENV')`

But still no success. The wierd part is, that `$_ENV` php variable contains every single variable from `.env` file.

Answer (score 319, accepted):

Since Laravel 5.2, the `env(...)` function will not work after you cached the config.

The [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0) says

> If you are using the `config:cache` command during deployment, you must make sure that you are only calling the `env` function from within your configuration files, and not from anywhere else in your application.

So the correct answer would be to

> If you are calling env from within your application, it is strongly recommended you add proper configuration values to your configuration files and call env from that location instead, allowing you to convert your env calls to config calls.

And I quoted it from the same [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0)

For a quick fix this will do:

```
 php artisan config:clear
```

But it will fail again as soon as configuration is cached, as should always be the case in production environments.

And now it should be clear why, when you tried `config:cache`, it did not help, even though it clears the config prior to caching.

Comment: Thank you, `php artisan config:clear` is the only thing that worked to get my AWS SES credentials to read.

Comment: So I think we should not directly use something like `env('APP_ENV') ` in our application. Instead, we should write a line in `config/app.php`: `'env' => env('APP_ENV'),`. Then, we use it in our code: `config('app.env')`.

Comment: @cosmos for anyone reading this, ALWAYS do that, `env` is only useful in any `config/*.php` file, never outside !!!!

Comment: "There are no commands defined in the "config" namespace." Still Laravel does not read  the .env file

Comment: cache clear did it for me

Answer (score 61):

Hope this command will save you

> php artisan config:clear

Answer (score 48):

The following Command worked for me.
I accidently cleared all the cache files, So `env('something')` was returning null.

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! This suddenly happened to me today -Laravel 8. This fixed it.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me on Laravel 8. Not being able to get the env values was driving me nuts. Thank you very much.

Comment: For some reason all commands like php artisan 'insertsomething':clear doesn't work, only this one worked for me

Comment: Still working this advice ;)

Comment: Laravel 8 gang too, thanks!

Answer (score 20):

Use `\Config::get('app.env');` instead of `env(APP_ENV);` because you're going to get the same error eventually and that's not good for a live website.

If you want to add custom variables from your ENV, go into your config app and find this:

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Environment
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value determines the "environment" your application is currently
    | running in. This may determine how you prefer to configure various
    | services your application utilizes. Set this in your ".env" file.
    |
    */

'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),
```

add a new line under "`'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),`", so for example, it could be the following:

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Environment
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value determines the "environment" your application is currently
    | running in. This may determine how you prefer to configure various
    | services your application utilizes. Set this in your ".env" file.
    |
    */

'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),
'key' => env('APP_KEY'),
```

You can call the "key" variable like this:

```
\Config::get('app.key');
```

Whenever you add a new variable like "key" to the app env, you'll need to use `config:cache` to reset the cache.

Comment: I am not sure but may be this bug only occurs in windows. but your solution resolved it in windows too. will it work in linux production environment?

Comment: @AmitShah, it is not a bug, it is a feature. Please check out my answer for details.

Answer (score 17):

Just run this command at your Laravel project root

```
rm bootstrap/cache/config.php
```

Comment: What a magic <3

Answer (score 15):

This is caused by configuration caching and can be temporarily solved with:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: Some users may need to do php artisan config:clear instead

Comment: Laravel 5.5 I had to run 'php artisan config:clear'. Thanks

Comment: php artisan config:cache is the reason why env() values are null. If you wish to cache your config and env vars then you shouldn't use env() anywhere else except config files because once cached env() will always return null. Although now I am also seeing config() and Config::get() helper return null after caching which is weird too.

Comment: follow up to above - ...So thats when you should realize that config() helper cannot directly access values in .env either. You will need to create or use existing config/<insert config file name>.php config file and create your config entry from .env and then use that mapped value.

Answer (score 5):

After trying below commands

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

If you still get null from `env('APP_ENV')` then try this `app()->environment()`. Hope this will don't return null. This works for me

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the accepted solution does not provide an appropriate solution for this problem!

The case: Since `Laravel 5.2`, if you call `env("key")` directly, it will always return `null` if you executed `php artisan config:cache` as last command.

**Accepted answer say** : execute `php artisan config:clear` as last command to solve problem! **This is not a solution!**, because we need always to execute `php artisan config:cache` as last command..

**So what is the solution?**

Here i need to explain solution for two of cases:

---

**Case 1 (Predefined keys)**: If you need to get value from `.env` file which created by Laravel project as (default .env file), or by third party plugin you already installed it and follow the correct installation procedure of installation:

1. Get the key name which listed in `.env` file and search for it in files of `laravel_root/config` folder (remember: all files in `config` folder returns results as array), for example i searched for `APP_URL` which per-defined by Laravel project as default:

[image]

As you say here I found tow results in tow config files, one in  `filesystem.php` and other in `app.php`, so to get any of these values in any php (Classes or view files, ... etc) on your laravel project just call it like this:

- For result which we found in `app.php` file, get it value by:

> config('app.env');

Here `app` is name of php file, and env is the key of array which returned as result of `app.php` file.

- For result which we found in `filesystems.php` file, get it value by:

> config('filesystems.public.url');

Here `filesystems` is name of php file, and **`public` is the key (level 1)**  and **`url` is the key (level 2)** of array which returned as result of `filesystems.php` file.

> Summary of this case: if you need get value of `APP_URL` in any php file of Laravel project you can get
> it by call `config('app.env')` function, whether the last command executed
> is `php artisan config:clear` or `php artisan config:cache`, It
> doesn't matter at all.

---

**Case 2 (Not predefined keys - if you need generate new custom environment key)**: See this answer for explain: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69707739/2877427

Answer (score 1):

Remember to check your `.env` file for **duplicate variable declarations**.

```
STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY="why-wont-this-key-get-outputted"

#...

# Because at the bottom of the .env file it is unset like this
STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY=
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old thread and the reason may not be the same. But the same issue happened to me.

The reason was I had an issue inside .env file. This is what I got in .env

```
TEST="e@1asa
```

Notice that ending quote is missing. And it should be like,

```
TEST="e@1asa"
```

All the env variables I added after that returned null due to this error.

Nothing written to error log even. So if you have met this error **try adding an example env variable as the first record of the file**. If it works and **record at last not working** there may be an error inside .env

Answer (score 0):

If the accepted answer doesn't fix the issue check if .env file has correct read and write permission given. If the file cannot be read by the framework / library then the values will always be null. I've come across this issue on one of my Lumen projects but after changing the file permissions it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**php artisan config:clear**.
Please run this command it will clear the config cache.
Its happening because the config file is cached and at the time of caching the values must be null.

Answer (score 0):

Always clear config cache whenever any modification is made on .env or any other config files

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).