# Laravel .env variable always returns null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I added this variable to .env file

> STRIPE_SECRET=a12345

I would like to dump the variable using routes/web.php

```
<?php
dd(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
```

But it looks like it always returns null.

Update : Updated .env file. I only removed DB_PASSWORD.

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:08txDXXatyYsP5WQ4ECz35Q7OyBEe8Vgb/zK5fZsHik=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost
APP_LOCALE=tr
APP_LC_ALL=tr_TR.utf8

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=gunluk
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=03ac580c85842d
MAIL_PASSWORD=1d6d902d296942
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=

STRIPE=a123
STRIPE_SECRET=a12345
```

Comment: try runing following commands php artisan config:clear and 
php artisan optimize

Comment: Are you sure you have an app key? Run `php artisan key:generate` to make sure and then try again.

Comment: After regenerating keys still it returns null.

Comment: your env not have STRIPE_SECRET but its STRIPE

Comment: Yes but tried to test whether it will dump STRIPE. It doesn't  dump neither STRIPE nor STRIPE_SECRET.

Comment: Hmm...this issue doesn't make sense. Is this a new app? Or did something change recently? What OS runs on the server?

Comment: Could you answer this questions: Where is placed your .env file? Have you tried to execute the `env("STRIPE")` call in tinker? The other env parameters works (like `env("APP_NAME")`?

Comment: @Desh901 my .env file resides in root of project. Output of `env("STRIPE")` or `env("APP_NAME")` is null when I execute this commands on php artisan tinker.

Comment: So basically it could be the fact that the configuration is cached and env values ar not loaded from `.env` file. Always access yout env variables within you through the `config` method. To test that run only the command `php artisan config:clear` and retry the above tests

Comment: @Desh901 now it works as expected. May you reply the thread so that I may offer bounty points.

Comment: Done, happy to hear that

Comment: Thanks. It says you may award your bounty in 11 hours.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.3 - env() always returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43243732/laravel-5-3-env-always-returns-null)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The main reason upon your issue is that you are caching your configuration. When running `php artisan config:cache` you're storing your configuration in your cache, and the next time Laravel will boot up it won't read the `.env` file because it detects that the configuration has been stored in the cache. Environment file should be used only to setup configuration files and then to access the value you're looking for you should use ONLY the `config` method.

Let's assume that you have the file `config/stripe.php` that consists of this content:

```
<?php

return [
    'secret' => env('STRIPE_SECRET', '')
];
```

Once you run `php artisan config:cache` access this value using ONLY the syntax `config('stripe.secret')` through your application code. Every time you update your config files and your `.env` you need to run `php artisan config:cache` again.

Answer (score 18):

First, there is no `STRIPE_SECRET` inside your `.env` file(As per before edit the question). So please make sure that your `.env` must have this variable. You should clear your configuration cache by executing following commands in the same order

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
```

Laravel cache your configuration files so the execution become faster. So everytime when you change the configuration files on server, you should clear the cache.

Additionally you can run these commands also to clear the other caches

```
php artisan cache:clear   //for clearing the cache
php artisan view:clear    //for clearing the compiled views
php artisan route:clear   //for clearing the routes cache
```

You can also create the routes for these commands and call the commands from the code also as

```
Route::get('/cache-clear', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    echo "Cache Cleard: ".$exitCode;
});

Route::get('/view-clear', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('view:clear');
    echo "View Cleard: ".$exitCode;
});

Route::get('/route-cache', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('route:cache');
    echo "Route Cached: ".$exitCode;
});

Route::get('/route-clear', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('route:clear');
    echo "Route Cache Cleared: ".$exitCode;
});

Route::get('/config-cache', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:cache');
    echo "Config Cached: ".$exitCode;
});

Route::get('/config-clear', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:clear');
    echo "Config Cache Cleared: ".$exitCode;
});
```

Answer (score 11):

if you have 
`STRIPE="a12345"` this in `.env` file or if you any change in `.env` file or `config` file then you fallow these steps

one more thing write the variable value in comma's like  `STRIPE="a12345"`

First run these commands

```
 1. php artisan config:clear
 2. php artisan cache:clear
 3. composer dump-autoload
```

and finally used this command to get variable

```
dd(env('STRIPE'));
```

this working for me

and  also 1 stupid suggestion: restart server

I have add all possible solution

Comment: This worked for me.  Tried steps 1 and 2 repeatedly (from other suggestions), but didn't work until I tried step 3 too.

Answer (score 4):

You can clear configuration cache using following commands

```
php artisan config:clear 
php artisan optimize
php artisan config:cache
```

Also make sure

If you are using the `config:cache` command during deployment, you must make sure that you are only calling the env function from within your configuration files, and not from anywhere else in your application.
If you are calling env from within your application, it is strongly recommended you add proper configuration values to your configuration files and call env from that location instead, allowing you to convert your env calls to config calls.

Reference [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-environment-detection-not-working?page=1):

**Update 1:**

Also make sure you have renamed `.env.example` to `.env file` by default laravel have `.env.example`

**Update 2**

As per your new update question your env file have `STRIPE` not `STRIPE_SECRET`
so you have access like this if its not typo error in question

```
env('STRIPE')
```

Comment: Still routes/web.php returns null.

Comment: are you sure you have .env file not .env.example

Comment: Sure I have an .env file.

Comment: okat .i have tried env method its working for me .strange erorr

Comment: are you able to access other db info

Comment: can you post entire env file

Comment: When I try `dd(getenv('DB_CONNECTION'));` still it return false.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155159/discussion-between-icoders-and-erdem).

Comment: as i noted your env contain STRIPE not STRIPE_SECRET

Comment: Yes but it shouldn't dump either of them.

Comment: have you ran php artisan config:cache .if still not working after this command just try to  composer update

Comment: After executing both comments still `dd(getenv('STRIPE_SECRET'));` output is false.

Answer (score 1):

`env(...)` function will return null after you cached the config. (starting from laravel 5.2 till current 5.7)

The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0) says

> If you are using the `config:cache` command during deployment, you must make sure that you are only calling the `env` function from within your configuration files, and not from anywhere else in your application.

So the correct answer would be to

> If you are calling env from within your application, it is strongly recommended you add proper configuration values to your configuration files and call env from that location instead, allowing you to convert your env calls to config calls.

And I quoted it from the same [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0)

But for a quick fix this will do:

> php artisan config:clear

Comment: Apart from running php artisan config:cache. If necessary, say I have API_DOMAIN=https://www.someaddress.com/ as a line in my .env file, which file do I put what line instead in? And what do I replace my env('API_DOMAIN') calls with?

Comment: if you are lazy put it in `\config\app.php`, if you feel like you are making a new api service connector use `\config\services.php`, if you feel like it is a big thing - create your own file.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend using the env('STRIPE') command to get a variable. In a loop, this command starts returning null after some iteration. Therefore, it is better to create a configuration file and use the command "config('file_name.variable_name)":

```
<?php
return [
    'sprite_secret' => env('STRIPE_SECRET', '')
];
```

Run these commands first

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
```

And use this command to get the value of the STRIPE_SECRET variable:

```
config('config_file.sprite_secret)
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you app is completely booted.

if you are running server with cmd then try restarting server.

and if it not works try clearing the cache using the methods above mentioned by @iCoders.

Comment: How should I boot app. This app runs on my own server so it restarted recently.

Comment: Where you are trying to get the variable

Comment: It still does not work. I try to get the variable in routes/web.php

Comment: Seems line u have STIPE key in your .env not STRIPE_SECRET

Comment: Seems like you don't have STRIPE_SECRET in you above mentioned .env file. Its STRIPE I guess you wanna get

Comment: Try getting env('STRIPE')
Not getenv('STRIPE')
You will get the value

Comment: I tried `dd(env('APP_URL'));` and `dd(env('STRIPE'));` both return null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155189/discussion-between-moeen-basra-and-erdem).

Comment: I saw your last comment after some time passed.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command on Linux:
`php artisan config:cache && php artisan config:clear && php artisan cache:clear && php artisan view:clear && php artisan route:clear`

And run this command on:
`php artisan config:cache & php artisan config:clear & php artisan cache:clear & php artisan view:clear & php artisan route:clear`

For more details you can explore this article: [Click here](https://www.thenexttutorial.com/2023/10/laravel-env-variable-always-returns-null.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem where `{{ env("APP_NAME", "X") }}` always returned `"X"`. I fixed it by running `composer dump-autoload` and now everything is fine.