# Laravel 5.5 - Redis::connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, redis, laravel-5.5

Something strange is happening with my Laravel installation. When I run

```
php artisan config:cache
```

I get the following error:

```
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
Exception message: 
Redis::connect(): php_network_getaddresses:
getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

When I clear the cache using `php artisan config:clear` the exception disappears. Does someone know where this comes from?

EDIT:

- Redis-Host in `.env` is `127.0.0.1`, so no address resolution is needed.
- Also the error occures when calling `$redis = new \Redis(); $redis->connect(env('REDIS_HOST'));`

Comment: What do `env('redis_host')` returns?

Comment: @EliasSoares it's empty :)

Comment: I found the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43243732/laravel-5-env-always-returns-null - you can not call `env()` after config has been cached.

Answer (score 0):

You have your cache driver set to Redis and your application can't connect to the Redis server on the host you provided. It is trying to connect when caching the config, check your redis connection parameters on `config/database.php` or change your cache driver on `config/cache.php`.
These values can also be set on your `.env` file if present.

Comment: Hi thank you, but thats not the problem, see the EDIT in my answer.

Comment: What do you get if you dump `config()->get('database')['redis']`?

Comment: I get: `Array ( [client] => predis [default] => Array ( [host] => 127.0.0.1 [password] => [port] => 6379 [database] => 0 )`

Comment: I found the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43243732/laravel-5-env-always-returns-null - you can not call `env()` after config has been cached.