# laravel try to connect to localhost database while the database is in external server

Tags: laravel

I am working on localhost and I would like to connect my laravel app to an external database. I put all my settings in :

config/database.php :

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'XX.XX.XXX.XXX'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', 'XXXX'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'name'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'username'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'),
    'charset' => 'latin-1',
    'collation' => 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => 'InnoDB',
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
    ]) : [],
],
```

.env :

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:X...
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DATABASE_URL=XX.XX.XXX.XXX:XXXX
DB_HOST=XX.XX.XXX.XXX
DB_PORT=XXXX
DB_DATABASE=name
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

I have the same error :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] access denied for user : 'username'@'@localhost'
```

It seems that the app try to connect to localhost database but my database is not in localhost.

Comment: After changing the details in `.env` run the command `php artisan config:cache` and try again, it will load the updated values

Comment: Thank you @MayankPandeyz but still the same problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53385384/1561929

Comment: Just for the sake of testing replace the `env()` calls in you database.php with the values directly. If the error goes away then your issue is probably cache for the .env file as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

If you served your project with artisan(php artisan serve) you kill it and start it again when you change something in .env file.

Could you try it?