# Accessing the contents of .env via the env Facade

Tags: php, laravel, dotenv

In my Laravel 7.x application, I added some basic configuration to my `.env` file, eg:

`MY_SECRET_KEY=foo`

In my controller, I am attempting to read in the value via the following:

`Log::debug("ENV[MY_SECRET_KEY]: " . env('MY_SECRET_KEY'));`

The result of the `env` shows up as an empty string in `storage/logs/laravel.log`:

`[2020-09-05 18:38:58] local.DEBUG: ENV[MY_SECRET_KEY]:`

I made sure to restart my docker container and verified that `.env` is indeed there and contains the populated `env` var. No typos.

Why else would it be coming up as empty?

Comment: is this similar to your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53385384/10573560

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably it's cached. Try this

```sh
php artisan config:clear
```