# Why phpunit is not getting the correct APP_ENV as specified in phpunit.xml?

Tags: xml, laravel, docker, phpunit

I'm using Laravel and this is my ./phpunit.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="FeatureTests">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>

        <testsuite name="UnitTests">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite_testing" />
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

I'm firing one of my test suites with the following command:

```
./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --testsuite UnitTests
```

Inside my test method I have:

```
public function testAllMandatoryData()
{
   dump(env('APP_ENV'));
   ....
}
```

It's displaying "local" I was expecting "testing" as specified in phpunit.xml

```
         <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
```

**Edit: additional details**
I have this laravel application running in a Docker container

On the docker-compose.yml I set some environment variables like:

```
environment:
  - APP_ENV=local
  - DB_HOST=192.168.0.22
  - DB_PORT=33306
  - DB_DATABASE=mydatabase
  - DB_USERNAME=homestead
  - DB_PASSWORD=homestead
```

What I've noticed is that directives in phpunit.xml like:

```
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
```

have no effect when the name is there in the docker-compose already.

Instead if I add some not defined in docker-compose.yml will be correctly set at phpunit runtime, like:

```
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite_test"/>
```

**end Edit**

What I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure you can override container variables at the application level?  Maybe these help: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3183, http://philippe.bourgau.net/docker-compose-trick-how-to-have-an-overridable-environment-variable-in-development-mode/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I try to answer myself with the best option I found.

If you set ENV variables at docker-compose.yml file you won't be able to overwrite them with phpunit.xml directives such as:

```
  <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
```

Then you should opt for removing (like in this example) APP_ENV variable set from docker-compose.yml

And rely on .env Laravel file

```
APP_ENV=local
```

With this setup, phpunit will be able to overwrite the APP_ENV to "testing"

I'm still not 100% sure this arrangement is needed, with all docker agent versions. Another host I have with another Docker version behaves differently.

Comment: Wrong answer. You can override it. Use force="true" attribute.

<env name="APP_ENV" value="testing" force="true"/>

Answer (score 22):

use

```
<env name="APP_ENV" value="testing" force="true"/>
<env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array" force="true"/>
<env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array" force="true"/>
<env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync" force="true"/>
<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite_testing" force="true"/>
```

Without the force parameter, it won't work. See this issue:
https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/2353
and the merged PR: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/pull/2723

Comment: @koalaok this should be the chosen answer, so that you can still use those env params in your docker-compose file

Answer (score 5):

Use `config('app.env')` instead.  `env()` values might be cached, in which case `php artisan config:clear` might help, though I've also had problems with accessing `env` values from command line environments.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40026893/what-is-difference-between-use-envapp-env-configapp-env-or-appenviron) and [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0).

Comment: Thanks but none of your suggestion will work for me.

Comment: Why not? Nobody can help if you don't give us the details.

Comment: Added some details from  discovery I found so far.

Comment: using php artisan config:clear worked for me and allowed my tests to run against the testing database. Their should be a better way for testing to get it to always connect to the testing database and not overwrite the primary database without wiping out this config. When I rebooted the docker setup the config came back so I would need to do this every time I rebooted the containers.

Comment: FYI: It would be config('app.env');. The config function uses dot notation. config('APP_ENV') will always be null.

Comment: thank you for this inspiration!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, .env variables seemed to be overriding the ones from my phpunit.xml, here are some of the solutions that could work:

1. Specify which phpunit.xml file to use when running phpunit, it may be using a wrong one. `vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration [path to your phpunit.xml]`
2. Clean the config cache. `php artisan config:cache`
3. If you're in a Docker container, the above action may not work for you. What I did was to delete manually the `bootstrap/cache` files.

Hope it helps!

Comment: for my case i'm using laradock, so i delete my local bootstrap/cache the run the test and it worked

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same problem when using Docker alongside docker-compose, and the fact was that my **docker-compose.yml** was loading Laravel's **.env** file.
So, I solved it by creating a **.env.docker** file and setting (*in docker-compose.yml*):

```
  env_file:
    - .env.docker
```

It worked like a charm, and PHPUnit was able to select my **.env.testing** file insted of **.env**

Answer (score 1):

I had to resort to this little hack to get the environment to 'testing', I had to put this in `TestCase.php`

```php
protected function setUp(): void
{
   parent::setUp();
   $this->app->detectEnvironment( function () {
      return 'testing';
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your config cache by running the command `php artisan config:clear`. It is because you probably ran the command `php artisan config:cache` before running your tests and your `APP_ENV` was cached as `local`.

Answer (score 0):

For docker users, I added a new `test` script to `composer.json` file:

```json
"test": [
        "DB_CONNECTION=sqlite && DB_DATABASE=:memory: && APP_ENV=testing && phpunit --colors=always --no-coverage"
        ],
```

This script is just overriding the environment variables defined in `docker-compose.json`

Answer (score 0):

For me, changing "env" tags to "server" resolved this problem where variables set in phpunit.xml were not taking effect.

```
<server name="APP_ENV" value="testing" force="true" />
```