# Environment variable working weird in FirebaseController of Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, firebase, environment-variables

I am trying to connect my localhost apps to firebase.

The firebase controller works fine with the code below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Kreait\Firebase;
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;
use Kreait\Firebase\Database;


class FirebaseController extends Controller
{
    protected $database;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->database = app('firebase.database');
    }

    public function index()
    {     
        $factory = (new Factory)
            ->withServiceAccount(__DIR__ . env('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'))
            ->withDatabaseUri(env('DATABASE_URI'));


        $database = $factory->createDatabase();

        $newPost = $database
            ->getReference('blog/posts')
            ->push([
                'title' => 'Post title',
                'body' => 'This should probably be longer.'
            ]);


        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($newPost->getvalue());
    }
}
```

but when I change the environment variable in .env from:

```
FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS=FirebaseKey.json
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/FirebaseKey.json
```

to

```
FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS=/FirebaseKey.json
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/FirebaseKey.json
```

by only added a foward slash at `FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS` then,  suddenly page crack. Error:

```
Kreait\Firebase\Exception\InvalidArgumentException
Invalid service account: /FirebaseKey.json can not be read:
SplFileObject::__construct(/FirebaseKey.json): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I am actually not using the `FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS` variable in anywhere else, or I shouldn't declaring this variable in `.env` file?

And also, when I replace the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` with `FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS` and change the value of `FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS` and `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` in `.env` file as show in the below:

```
FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS=/FirebaseKey.json
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/FirebaseKey.json
```

it will display the same error.

```
Kreait\Firebase\Exception\InvalidArgumentException
Invalid service account: /FirebaseKey.json can not be read: 
SplFileObject::__construct(/FirebaseKey.json): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

So the question is why using `FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS` variable, then it cannot read the .json file but when using `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` everything is fine?

Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9AKr.png) of the directory.

Comment: Did you try using absolute directories? Also, you should define env info within the config files and use the config helper in Laravel elsewhere. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40026893/what-is-difference-between-use-envapp-env-configapp-env-or-appenviron

Comment: Are you trying to access two separate Firebase projects in one application or why are you re-instantiating the factory in the index action? With the Laravel package this should never be necessary. Have a look at https://github.com/kreait/laravel-firebase/issues/96#issuecomment-886030038, this might help. Also https://github.com/kreait/laravel-firebase#usage

Comment: Also, unless the credentials file is indeed located in the root directory of your filesystem, try removing the leading slash in the file path 

Comment: @jeromegamez Can you provide the resource on how to avoid using re-instantiating because I am quite new to oop php...

Comment: @Denusklo https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/5.x/realtime-database.html#initializing-the-realtime-database-component (the "With Dependency Injection" section). Also, if you'd like, and have more questions, feel free to join the Discord Server linked in the readme of the project - everything is easier than the comments section on Stack Overflow 