# Why "App::environment()" and "php artisan env" returns different results?

Tags: laravel

This is the `env` variable in my config/app.php

```php
'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),
```

I changed the `APP_ENV` variable to `staging` from .env like the following:

```
APP_ENV=staging
```

I run `php artisan config:clear`.

After that, `php artisan env` returned:

```
Current application environment: staging
```

However, the `App::environment()` still returns `local`.

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    dd(App::environment());
});
```

Any ideas? Did I miss something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is difference between use env('APP\_ENV'), config('app.env') or App::environment() to get app environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40026893/what-is-difference-between-use-envapp-env-configapp-env-or-appenviron)

Comment: Please add code from the `config/app.php` to the post, where the environment config is set.

Comment: @NikolaiKiselev I add the content of my `config/app.php`, is there anything that I need to provide? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, on the application level, the environment variable is set correctly. The value should be `staging`.

However, it can be overridden by your web server settings.

> The current application environment detection can be overridden by
> defining a server-level APP_ENV environment variable.

[Source: Laravel 9 Determining The Current Environment](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/configuration#determining-the-current-environment)

You could check the web server settings.

E.g. with Apache server, the environment variable could be set, in files like `httpd.conf` as following:

```
SetEnv ENVIRONMENT "local"
```

Comment: Thank you for these information. I use sail to develop laravel website, there is a similar setting `environment=LARAVEL_SAIL="1"` in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf`. Maybe it is not a good idea to modify the setting. So I think  I need to find another way to to test if `App::environment()` works.

Comment: @Autodesk, Laravel Sail should definitely pick up changes in `.env`. Did you restart Sail after making the change?

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! But I didn't restart Sail, because I use Sail with dev-container on vscode, so I decided to rebuild the container.