# How can setup subdomain in laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I am trying to set up a subdomain in my project, but it is not working for some reason.

```php
Route::domain('{username}.' . env('APP_URL'))->group(function () {
    return "test";
});
```

It is not returning a thing. Instead, it is going to the main domain. What should I do?

Comment: Recommended use `config('app.url')` instead of `env('APP_URL')`, if you wish to cache your configuration values. [What difference between use `env()` and `config()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42393294/15167500) or [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75038854/15167500) for working `config()` method in `web.php`.

Comment: You don't have any routes defined, how would you expect it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a response you need to return it from a route, not from the group function directly.

```
Route::domain('{username}.' . env('APP_URL'))->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function ($username) {
        return $username;
    });
});
```